# why must press every time to see telegram messages

Tags: html, asp.net-core-webapi, telegram

i send html messages from my c# server to my telegram bot on android

only html message required to press to see the message, how to cancel it?

i want to see all messages without press on them every time

all the message looks like the image below

> string msg = $@"<span class=""tg-spoiler"" style=""direction:rtl;
> text-align:right;display:block"">
> ---------------------------------------------------------------- **{item.CoinName}** **p: **{item.ercentage}**** **np:
> {item.NewPrice}** **op:   {item.OldPrice}** **v:
> {item.Volume}**
> ------------------------------------------------------------";

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please share your code and message. Those are 'spoilers', if you show your code we can tell you were those are added.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending messages as spoilers. Spoilers needs a single click to reveil there real message

---

Looking at [Telegram's formatting options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options), you are using either using

```
||my message||
```

Or, when passing as HTML:

```
<span class="tg-spoiler">my message</span>
<tg-spoiler>my message</tg-spoiler>
```

---

Remove those spoiler tags and you're good to go.